# Design crushing to corner PyQT5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm kinda new to this so I'm basically just copy pasting the stuff from tutorials I've done to make it work.

I've made a designer.ui file with QtDesigner and now I've exported it to Python code. If I use the `-x` command then run the design Python it works fine, but if I import it to another file (so I can make connections) then it all crushes down to 1 place rather than sticking to the grid layout base.

If I launch my Main.py file (not designer code) then I get the error `QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout` but I don't see where I'm adding a layout within my Main code...

My code is:
https://gist.github.com/crabcrabcam/3a6a9e847791117616d18ada0895f868

Thanks for any help :) If you need some more stuff just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because the `QMainWindow` class already has a layout where the `QStatusBar`, `QMenubar`, etc. are placed. To customize it just add `QWidget` with the `setCentralWidget`.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(w)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.btnOpenFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.btnOpenFile.setObjectName("btnOpenFile")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnOpenFile)
        self.btnSaveFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.btnSaveFile.setObjectName("btnSaveFile")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnSaveFile)
        self.btnSendEmail = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.btnSendEmail.setObjectName("btnSendEmail")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.btnSendEmail)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.txtEditMain = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(MainWindow)
        self.txtEditMain.setObjectName("txtEditMain")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.txtEditMain, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btnClear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.btnClear.setObjectName("btnClear")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnClear, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Another observation, when you inherit from a class you must call the constructor of that class. In your case you are inheriting from `QMainWindow` then you should call the `QMainWindow` constructor and not `QWidget`.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. That's got it working. How can I get the designer to add the `w = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)` part? Or will I just have to go into there and add it every time.

Comment: He always adds it, it seems to me strange that he did not do it, you have not eliminated something when you designed it.

Comment: I set the main layout as grid then put in a horizontal layout inside a grid place. It could be that the QWidget class is a layout (changed to vertical now)

Comment: Alright, so I worked it out. Instead of making a `QMainWindow` in the designer I made a `QWidget`, I was then making my `MainWindow` class with a `QMainWindow` despite it being a `QWidget`

Thanks for the help :)